# Как сделать постоянное обновление api | Python requests

Tags: python, requests, telebot

Не понимаю как сделать постоянное обновление api. при вводе команды постоянно выдаёт одну цитату вместо новой. (если перезапустить скрипт то выдается новая)

```
import telebot
import requests
import logging

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = telebot.TeleBot('Token')

url = 'https://favqs.com/api/qotd'

response = requests.get(url)
jsonResponse = response.json()
citata = jsonResponse["quote"]["body"]
author = jsonResponse["quote"]["author"]


@client.message_handler(commands=['quote'])
def quote(message):
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, citata + f'\n Author: ' + author)


client.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

не буду удалять, оставлю вдруг кто-то как я затупит и не поймет что нужно было просто это в функцию запихнуть, хаха

```
        
def quote(message):
    response = requests.get(url)
    jsonResponse = response.json()
    citata = jsonResponse["quote"]["body"]
    author = jsonResponse["quote"]["author"]
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, citata + f'\n Author: ' + author)
```